# How to implement execution plans using siddhi?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

First of all let me description my requirement:

**data.csv**:
column one is id,column two is vlaue.

```
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,86
5,87
6,88
7,89
8,86
9,0
10,0
11,0
12,0
13,0
14,86
15,87
16,88
17,89
18,0
19,0
20,0
```

here is my **InputStream** and my **OutPutStream**:

```
id int,value int
```

**data.csv** will insert into **InputStream** by using **Event Stream Simulator**.

If there are five consecutive value>=85, I would record the first id,value into **OutPutStream**.
For example,I will record id=4,value=86 ,but id=14 to id=17 i will ignore it.

So how can i write siddhi script in execution plans to implement it?

==========================================================================

**data2.csv**:

```
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,86
5,87
6,88
7,89
8,86
9,87
10,88
11,89
12,90
13,91
14,86
15,87
16,88
17,89
18,90
19,90
20,90
21,0
22,0,
23,87
24,85
25,86
26,0
27,17
...
200,91
201,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exactly five consecutive values >= 85

```
from every a1=InputStream[value>=85], a2=InputStream[value>=85]+, a3=InputStream[value<85]
select a1.id, a1.value
having (not (a2[3] is null)) and (a2[4] is null)
insert into OutPutStream;
```

For more than five consecutive values >= 85

```
from every a1=InputStream[value>=85], a2=InputStream[value>=85]+, a3=InputStream[value<85]
select a1.id, a1.value
having (not (a2[3] is null))
insert into OutPutStream;
```

Comment: Hi Grainier,i use the second siddhi query (**for more than five consecutive value >=85**) because i'm not sure what time the value will smaller that 85 in actual situation.But i meet another problem:if i want insert data when:id=8,value=86(i'm not sure what time the value will smaller that 85 but i need insert when five consecutive values >= 85...).

Comment: So i made some fake data like data2.scv and test it,i must wait the data running out and then insert into OutPutStream.I want if have **5** consecutive value >=85(but not exactly five,could be more than five), for example from id=4,value=86 to id=8,value=86 then i want insert id=8,value=86 to OutPutStream.I hope you can understand what i say because my english is sucks.

Comment: I'm not quite clear with the requirement here, do you want to output **every** five consecutive value >= 85? (i.e at event 8,86: output 4,86 / at event 9,87: output 5,87 / ...). Basically this will output 4,86 / 5,87 / 6,88 / 7,89 / 8,86 / ... since each of them were followed by five consecutive events with value >=85.

Then again, when you say "for example from id=4,value=86 to id=8,value=86 then i want insert id=8,value=86 to OutPutStream", it doesn't match your initial requirement of emitting **first** id, value to OutPutStream, right?

Comment: Thank you for your patience!Let me explain what i wanna do.I wanna monitor the event ,if i found value >=85(assume the id = 4),i will begin counting,if the next four consecutive  event value >=85 too(assume the id = 5/6/7/8),i will record the 5th event (value>=85,i.e  id=8).And then i will wait the value of event decrease ,lower than 85,at the time i will monitor again ,wait the value of event >=85 and counting... and again...

Comment: Plz look up the data2.scv(i updated it),when i found id=23,value=87, i will counting, and waiting the next four consecutive  value >=85,but the id=26,value=0,so i will clear the counting,wait next value >=85 and restart to counting.

Comment: My question now is, if the value has been greater than 85, for a long period of time greater than 85, I had to wait until the value in order to record a piece of data is less than 85, there is a continuous five records over 85 when I should immediately record, I need this effect.this comment by using google translate,i hope you can understand :)

Comment: @willxiang Please refer to my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/q/39009292/1805178

Answer (score 0):

```
from every a1=InputStream[value>=85], a1=InputStream[value>=85]<4> 
select a1.id, a1.value
insert into OutPutStream;
```

Should work!

Comment: Hi suho thank you but it's not work...I'm using wso2das-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT