# How can i pick out value from consecutive value of event by using siddhi

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, siddhi, wso2-cep

for example, that is data:

```
1,1470732420000,0
2,1470732421000,0
3,1470732422000,0
4,1470732423000,86
5,1470732424000,87
6,1470732425000,88
7,1470732426000,84
8,1470732427000,0
9,1470732428000,0
10,1470732429000,0
11,1470732430000,89
12,1470732431000,89
13,1470732432000,87
14,1470732433000,89
15,1470732434000,85
16,1470732435000,89
17,1470732436000,89
18,1470732437000,87
19,1470732438000,86
20,1470732439000,88
21,1470732440000,0
22,1470732441000,0
23,1470732442000,0
24,1470732443000,87
25,1470732444000,85
26,1470732445000,86
27,1470732446000,0
28,1470732447000,0
29,1470732448000,0
30,1470732449000,0
```

column one is **id**,column two is **timestamp**,column three is **value**,1 sec interval between the timestamp.

i want monitoring the value of event,if i found out value>=85(e.g. id=4), i will starting counting,if the next two consecutive value>=85(e.g. id=5/id=6),then i will put the third value of event to OutputStream.(e.g. id=6,value=88,timestamp=1470732425000)

at the same time i clear the counting and wait value lower than 85(e.g. id=7,value=84), then i will monitoring again,when i found out value>=85(e.g. id=11,value=89) i will starting counting,if the next two consecutive value>=85(e.g. id=12/id=13),then i will put the third value of event to OutputStream.(e.g. id=13,value=87,timestamp=1470732432000)...

all this is i wanna do,before i post this ask, i've got an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893507/how-to-implement-execution-plans-using-siddhi),i've tried this code:

```
from every a1=InputStream[value>=85], a2=InputStream[value>=85]+, a3=InputStream[value<85]
select a2[1].id, a2[1].value
having (not (a2[1] is null))
insert into OutPutStream;
```

and it works,but i found out it will insert the value into OutputStream after the value<=85,and what i want is if i got three consecutive value>=85 then i insert into the value immediately.(i don't want to wait if the next value>=85 all the times)
in fact, i just wanna record value of third seconds in  three consecutive seconds value(>=85) .
i'm using wso2das-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Do you want to monitor 3 consecutive events each time or would this vary?

Comment: The query depends on what sort of output you want from this. Can you kindly specify the answers you want to get for given example? Whether you want to get IDs 6,  13 and 26 as output (due to your specification of an intermediate event with value < 85) or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though DAS (Siddhi) supports sequence/pattern processing, for your requirement you might need to write a custom extension. I have written a sample window processor extension to cater your requirement ([source code](https://github.com/grainier/custom-siddhi-extensions/tree/master/siddhi-extension-condition-window)). Download and place [siddhi-extension-condition-window-1.0.jar](https://github.com/grainier/custom-siddhi-extensions/blob/master/siddhi-extension-condition-window/dist/siddhi-extension-condition-window-1.0.jar?raw=true) in `<das_home>/repository/components/lib/` directory and restart the server. Refer to the [test case](https://github.com/grainier/custom-siddhi-extensions/blob/master/siddhi-extension-condition-window/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/extension/custom/ConditionWindowProcessorTestCase.java#L50) to get an idea of the usage of the extension.